# Lua Loop doesn't preform all the actions inside itself (the setFillcolor() command specifically)

Tags: arrays, list, loops, lua, coronasdk

I am working on a game in Corona (with Lua) where the player colours in a plant and then adds it to a box. once the player has made enough plants a dinosaur walks over and eats the plants. after which the dinosaur is supposed to change colour filtering through the colours used to colour in the plants.

```
    -- this creates a loop that will cycle through the table "RecentColours" and "change the dinosaurs colour each time and" then stop on the last colour used
    X=1
    --changes dino colour
    for ListColors = 1, #RecentColours do
      Colour = RecentColours[X]
      Dino:setFillColor(unpack(Colour))
      X = X + 1
      print(unpack(Colour))
      --sets CurrentColour to the current colour of the dinosaur
      CurrentColour = Colour
    end
    --emptys dinour colour list
    for ListColors = 1, #RecentColours do
      Y = #RecentColours
      table.remove(RecentColours,Y)
    end
```

this loop runs for the length of a list of colours but the problem is the dinosaur only changes to the last colour in the list rather then cycleing through all of them

I have tried changing the style of loop but that changed nothing and i have tried a .preformwithdelay event and I have tried putting into its own function.

I have also tested with printing to the console and It definitely adds all the colours to the list and it definitely runs through the whole list as it prints the current part of the table that it's up to

---

*The comments helped greatly and solved the problem. but if you know a way to slow down a loop I would love to know*

Comment: You are changing the colors all at once.  Instead of "change-and-wait" strategy.  Don't use Lua loop.  Use timer and set next color in timer callback routine.

Comment: to clear table you can write RecentColours = {} instead of removing elements one by one